# letsencrypt-auto not working after CentOS update

Tags: centos, https, vps, lets-encrypt

After having my CentOS VPS updated to version 7.3, letsencrypt stopped working.

When running a letsencrypt-auto command (like # letsencrypt-auto --help) I get the following error:

```
Error: couldn't get currently installed version for /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt:
./letsencrypt-auto: /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt: /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/python2: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The python2 file does exist in that directory.

I'm not sure where to start and I'm not an expert on this. But this happened after I updated CentOS from an older version.

Any ideas what can be causing this and how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

As per the log submitted by your end. Yours let's encrypt installation path is

```
/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/
```

When you are trying to auto-renew the let's encrypt SSL, it is not able to find the correct file and folders in the path described.

**1. You may check the directory of path of let's encrypt installation and verify if all files and folders are there.**

**2. You can again re-install the let's encrypt and after that can install or renew certificate using below listed commands.**

```
    Installing Letsencrypt free SSL steps

    1. git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt /opt/letsencrypt
    2. cd /opt/letsencrypt/
    3. git reset --hard ce4e00569e6d8ed3d51c5a078d4281bec5f8e5f0
    4 ./letsencrypt-auto --no-self-upgrade renew
    5 ./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d enteryourdomainname.com

    For Renew
    1. crontab -e
    2. 15 5 * * 5 /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew >> /var/log/le-renew.log
    (The cron job we have just created will renew an SSL certificate every Friday at 5:15 A.M. by running the following script)
```

For detailed instructions on Installation of Let's Encrypt SSL [CLICK HERE](https://linuxtogether.org/lets-encrypt-ssl-installation-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the ~/.local/share/letsencrypt folder might have been a remnant of the old installation.

I did:

```
# rm -rf ~/.local/share/letsencrypt
```

Then I ran some letsencrypt-auto command again

```
# /letsencrypt-auto --help
```

This started a whole setup process, installing python packages etc. After this, letsencrypt worked fine again.